# Invalid signature when trying to apt-get update on Kali

Tags: apt, kali-linux

I'm getting an invalid signature error when I try to `apt-get update`:

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease

Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release 

Hit:4 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/dev/ InRelease                      

Hit:5 http://deb.i2p2.no unstable InRelease                         

Get:6 http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.5 kB]

Err:6 http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/kali kali-rolling InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: okay i will try my best but can you suggest me why this kind of error occurs

Comment: It looks like you need to import the key that has the fingerprint ED444FF07D8D0BF6. The [kali forums seem to have a solution.](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?18079-Public-key-error)

Comment: if you are a "noob", you shouldn't be using kali.  use a distro that isn't  deliberately broken and crippled.  any general purpose distro will do.

Answer (score 59):

Per: https://twitter.com/kalilinux/status/959515084157538304, your archive-keyring package is outdated.  You need to do this (as root):

```
wget -q -O - https://archive.kali.org/archive-key.asc  | apt-key add
```

Comment: thats what fixes my issue amazing, thank you

Comment: No valid openpgp data found (in my case).

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
wget https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/k/kali-archive-keyring/kali-archive-keyring_2018.1_all.deb
apt install ./kali-archive-keyring_2018.1_all.deb
apt-get update
```

[Kali forum](https://forums.kali.org/printthread.php?t=38858&pp=10&page=1) have this thread where you can look for further if this don't work.

Comment: This is tethered to the version of that package and therefore no longer works. See the second part of [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/422114/87770) for how to perform this method more reliably.

Answer (score 5):

You're missing the key that Kali uses to sign their packages. You can use `gpg` to download the key and `apt-key add` to add it:

```
gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  ED444FF07D8D0BF6
gpg -a --export ED444FF07D8D0BF6 | sudo apt-key add -
```