# Error while installing dhcpd

Tags: kali-linux, dhcp, isc-dhcpd

In order to use Fluxion 2 I need to install these missing components first:[image]
I used the command sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-common
But got the following error:[image]
This is what happens after I run the command sudo apt-get update.[image]

How to get Fluxion 2 working on my case?

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: @cas oh ok...sorry for those pictures... I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you what to do: run

```
apt-get update
```

and try again. You should, however, be installing `isc-dhcp-server`, as requested by the Fluxion installer.

To fix the key issue, see the answers to [Invalid signature for Kali Linux repositories : "The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/421821/86440).