# Unable to install git - GPG signature problems

Tags: terminal, apt, gpg

I recently installed Kali Rolling for WSL and I can't install git or many other packages.

Here's the error I get when trying to install git:

```
$ sudo apt install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  git-man libcurl3-gnutls libedit2 liberror-perl libexpat1 libgdbm-compat4 libgdbm6 libperl5.28 libx11-6 libx11-data
  libxau6 libxcb1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxmuu1 openssh-client patch perl perl-modules-5.28 xauth
Suggested packages:
  gettext-base git-daemon-run | git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-email git-gui gitk gitweb git-cvs git-mediawiki
  git-svn keychain libpam-ssh monkeysphere ssh-askpass ed diffutils-doc perl-doc libterm-readline-gnu-perl
  | libterm-readline-perl-perl make libb-debug-perl liblocale-codes-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  git git-man libcurl3-gnutls libedit2 liberror-perl libexpat1 libgdbm-compat4 libgdbm6 libperl5.28 libx11-6
  libx11-data libxau6 libxcb1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxmuu1 openssh-client patch perl perl-modules-5.28 xauth
0 upgraded, 21 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 17.0 MB/17.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 94.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 perl-modules-5.28 all 5.28.1-6
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Err:2 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libgdbm6 amd64 1.18.1-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Err:3 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libgdbm-compat4 amd64 1.18.1-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Err:4 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libperl5.28 amd64 5.28.1-6
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Err:5 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 perl amd64 5.28.1-6
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Err:6 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libedit2 amd64 3.1-20181209-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Err:7 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 openssh-client amd64 1:7.9p1-10
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Err:8 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libcurl3-gnutls amd64 7.64.0-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Err:9 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libexpat1 amd64 2.2.6-1
```

So, I tried running updating my repository list:

```
$ sudo apt update --fix-missing
Get:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.5 kB]
Err:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
Fetched 30.5 kB in 1s (25.6 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

That lead me to find [this page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/421827/447261) but since I don't have gpg installed and get the same error as when installing git if I try to, I tried the other suggestion they added:

```
$ wget -q -O - https://archive.kali.org/archive-key.asc | apt-key add
E: gnupg, gnupg2 and gnupg1 do not seem to be installed, but one of them is required for this operation
```

So now I don't know what else to try to get this to work.

BTW sorry for the long post, the errors were quite long.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I also tried [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/422114/447261) and the rest of the answers on that question. Here are the commands and outputs I got:

```
$ sudo apt install kali-archive-keyring
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
kali-archive-keyring is already the newest version (2018.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
$ sudo dpkg -i kali-archive-keyring_2020.2_all.deb
(Reading database ... 17118 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack kali-archive-keyring_2020.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking kali-archive-keyring (2020.2) over (2018.1) ...
Setting up kali-archive-keyring (2020.2) ...
Installed kali-archive-keyring as a trusted APT keyring.
```

Comment: Try [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/422114/332764) instead.

Comment: @Freddy forgot to mention but I also tried the other solutions on that page, but none of them work. I've edited my original post with the error.

Comment: So it seems you updated the keyring. What happens if you run `sudo apt update` now?

Comment: @Freddy I forgot to run sudo apt update to use the new keychain, thanks!