# kali Linux WSL 2 sudo update command is not working

Tags: debian, apt, kali-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[image: when i run the command this shows up]
hello,
i'm total newbie in linux space, place help me how to update the kali command they used in youtube video is seem like not working for me.

[image: my nano /etc/apt/sources.list]

what i'm doing wrong pls tell me...
i even put s in https
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Unix & Linux Stack.  As a heads-up, [please don't post code/commands/logs/errors/etc. as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933).  From WSL, it's very easy to put the output onto the Windows clipboard.  To capture both standard output and error (and still output to the screen), use `sudo apt update 2>&1 | tee >(clip.exe)` for example.

Comment: I'm assuming that you either installed via `wsl --install -d kali` or via the manual installation guide.  If that's the case, see this question - [Kali Linux on WSL break after upgrade](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/680382/kali-linux-on-wsl-break-after-upgrade).  The best alternative is to install from the Microsoft Store, if you have that option.  If not, I provide some alternatives on how to handle the manual install.

Comment: If the link that I provided answered your question, then please do check the option that you see at the top of this question which confirms it.  That will "close out" the question so that people don't see it when they look for open questions to answer.  If that link didn't solve your problem, then please let us know as well so that we can attempt to help you.