# Unable to install anything on kali Linux 2019.1

Tags: kali-linux

This is my `/etc/apt/sources.list` contain

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free 
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

a command like `apt-get update` or installing anything like `apt-get install terminator`. these commands are not working.
yet I am unable to update it or download anything. I have Linux 2019.1. As it is an old version but I need it for my work. How to fix this issue?
After running command `sudo apt-get update` I got output

```
Get:1 http://kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.6 kB]
Get:2 http://kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw/kali kali-bleeding-edge InRelease [14.1 kB]
Err:1 http://kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
Get:3 http://kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw/kali kali-experimental InRelease [23.0 kB]
Err:2 http://kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw/kali kali-bleeding-edge InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
Err:3 http://kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw/kali kali-experimental InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw/kali kali-rolling InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw/kali kali-bleeding-edge InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-bleeding-edge InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw/kali kali-experimental InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-experimental InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Could you fill the term »unable« with some hints? What command does produce what reaction (message, error, hangs, return without output)?

Comment: Sir I have updated my question

Comment: Please provide the error message that you get when you do `apt install something` / `apt update` .

Comment: E; unable to locate package

Comment: You might want to learn more about Linux before you jump into using Kali or you're not going to get very far

Comment: @dcom-launch sir, I am not doing some big work it is a simple step for my sources.list file has a kali Linux rolling repository address. I only want to install some packages which I am unable to do due to this error. I have searched for every possible solution out there but none of that is working. so I posted it here to get the exact answer.

Comment: Post exact output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: @roaima thank you for the suggestion I updated the Question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid signature for Kali Linux repositories : "The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421821/invalid-signature-for-kali-linux-repositories-the-following-signatures-were-i)

Comment: @roaima no sir these are not working

Comment: "not working" means almost nothing. Be precise. Update your question to explain what you've tried, what happened, etc

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed `kali-rolling` , `kali-bleeding-edge` and `kali-experimental`.

To install package from `kali-rolling` use:

```
sudo apt-get install terminator/kali-rolling
```

To install package from `kali-bleeding-edge` use:

```
sudo apt-get install terminator/kali-bleeding-edge
```

To solve the gpg key error [see this Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421821/invalid-signature-for-kali-linux-repositories-the-following-signatures-were-i).

Comment: Sir not working this does not work. My Sources.list doesnt have anything else like experimental or blending. My sources.list file has only these two lines that are given in the question

Comment: As you've been told in a comment to the question "does not work" means almost nothing! Be specific about what you do and what error you get. In proper Debian (and I guess descendants like kali have inherited that), you can add sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`, could they be there?