# WSL Linux - Kali SET Package Install issue

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, debian-installer

I'm fairly new to kali-linux, so I apologize for my lack of expertise.

I had installed Kali-Linux and Ubuntu successfully and updated everything. However, when installing [Packages](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/metapackages/) for Kali (only had the bare minimum of Kali installed) I came upon an issue, in every successive package un-met dependencies kept popping up that wouldn't be installed, no matter the package they would lead back to a package called '[set](https://www.kali.org/tools/set/)' that wouldn't install (its part of the kali-linux-headless package install). Working in root.

When trying to fix the install of '[set](https://www.kali.org/tools/set/)' this happens below.

It LOOKS like an issue with the archive not being in Debian format, but I'm honestly not sure what the actual issue is or how to fix it.

1. I've tried re-installing 'headless' and associated packages.
2. Searched online for the issue but came up with this issue happening for custom-packages in the file being 'broken'.
3. Also have tried getting a new [Key](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421821/invalid-signature-for-kali-linux-repositories-the-following-signatures-were-i) for the archive signature error.

Would love any advice anyone could provide or direct me to for this

```
sudo apt install set
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  sendmail-bin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  set
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1393 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/39.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 50.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
E: Invalid archive signature
E: Internal error, could not locate member control.tar{.zst,.lz4,.gz,.xz,.bz2,.lzma,}
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/set_8.0.3+git20200609-0kali2_all.deb
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
dpkg-deb: error: '/var/cache/apt/archives/set_8.0.3+git20200609-0kali2_all.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/set_8.0.3+git20200609-0kali2_all.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/set_8.0.3+git20200609-0kali2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the downloaded `set` package is corrupted (probably incomplete) on your system. The file in [the repository](http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/s/set/) is fine, so delete your cached version and try again:

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt install set
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried what you suggested to sadly no avail; same error. Also I tried `dpkg -r set` which yielded `dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove set which isn't installed` and then `apt -f install` giving the same error