# Signatures becomes invalid for apt

Tags: debian, apt

When doing `apt update`, I get this error line:

```
Err :6 https://packages.sury.org/php bookworm InRelease
  Les signatures suivantes ne sont pas valables : EXPKEYSIG B188E2B695BD4743 DEB.SURY.ORG Automatic Signing Key <deb@sury.org>

W: Une erreur s'est produite lors du contrôle de la signature. Le dépôt n'est pas mis à jour et les fichiers d'index précédents seront utilisés. Erreur de GPG : https://packages.sury.org/php bookworm InRelease : Les signatures suivantes ne sont pas valables : EXPKEYSIG B188E2B695BD4743 DEB.SURY.ORG Automatic Signing Key <deb@sury.org>
W: Impossible de récupérer https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/bookworm/InRelease  Les signatures suivantes ne sont pas valables : EXPKEYSIG B188E2B695BD4743 DEB.SURY.ORG Automatic Signing Key <deb@sury.org>
W: Le téléchargement de quelques fichiers d'index a échoué, ils ont été ignorés, ou les anciens ont été utilisés à la place.
```

Translated into english, it's this:

```
Err :6 https://packages.sury.org/php bookworm InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid : EXPKEYSIG B188E2B695BD4743 DEB.SURY.ORG Automatic Signing Key <deb@sury.org>

W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://packages.sury.org/php bookworm InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG B188E2B695BD4743 DEB.SURY.ORG Automatic Signing Key <deb@sury.org>
W: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/bookworm/InRelease The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG B188E2B695BD4743 DEB.SURY.ORG Automatic Signing Key <deb@sury.org>
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule, `EXPKEYSIG` errors mean that the corresponding key needs to be updated (or replaced with a new one). In some cases that must be done manually (see [Invalid signature for Kali Linux repositories : "The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/421821/86440) for example).

In this particular instance, the correct way to keep the repository signatures up-to-date is [described in the repository’s `README.txt`](https://packages.sury.org/php/README.txt):

```
curl -sSLo /tmp/debsuryorg-archive-keyring.deb https://packages.sury.org/debsuryorg-archive-keyring.deb
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/debsuryorg-archive-keyring.deb
```

Once that package is installed, and the repository configured in APT, it will be updated from the repository, avoiding key expiration issues.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, be sure you have the right package installed by running `apt-get update && apt-get install ca-certificates`.

Then, if it's not fixed, the issue comes from the expiration of the verification of the sury certificate. To fix it, you should run :

```
apt-key adv --fetch-keys 'https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg' > /dev/null 2>&1
```

If the command `apt-key` doesn't exist, you can use `wget` to update the key like this:

```
wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
```